# Wormhole related experiments?

Tags: spacetime, wormholes

Are there any simple "experiments" that can be done in a high school science lab that could demonstrate some sort of basic principals of wormholes or spacetime? Or sort of proving how long something would take to get through a wormhole or why you wouldn't be able to travel through them etc.

Comment: Surely you can't be serious

Comment: @zephyr Ha, im not asking to create my own wormhole, more about somehow trying to demonstrate the science behind it... showing how it could be possible or why it couldn't...

Comment: cross-posted to TP.SE http://theoreticalphysics.stackexchange.com/q/1002/189

Comment: There's nothing against you travelling through a stable wormhole. Few dangers, but they can be countered.

Comment: [Cross-posting is strong discouraged](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/896/520).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My favorite explanation of something similar to a wormhole is this, from Madeline L'Engle's *A Wrinkle in Time*

> Mrs. Who took a portion of her white robe in her hands and held it tight.
>
> "You see," Mrs. Whatsit said, "if a very small insect were to move from the section of skirt in Mrs. Who's right hand to that in her left, it would be quite a long walk for him if he had to walk straight across."
>
> Swiftly Mrs. Who brought her hands, still holding the skirt, together.
>
> “Now, you see," Mrs. Whatsit said, "he would be there, without that long trip. That is how we travel."

There's a bit more after this on dimensions, but it doesn't completely explain the issue (plus it uses some slightly wrong physics--it is, after all, a children's book)

You can do this explanation with a string. Then show them that a string (one-dimensional) had to be bent into a two-dimensional loopy thing.

Then, do the same thing with a piece of paper. Here, a 2D paper is bent into a 3D thing.

Now try to explain how this is possible in the real world--bending of 3D space into 4D spacetime in a loopy manner.

It would help if you explained the standard rock-in-a-rubber-sheet analogy of general relativity at first. Of course, I've seen this particular analogy lead to misconceptions/confusions frequently. But there's no way that I know of to explain it correctly without confusing the lot of them.